# Expanded Widget doesn't expand when space becomes available

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm creating a ListView.builder that contains every "post" in FireBase database. In one post there must be 3 parts; post title, post text, post photo(if it included by user). And I'm trying to design this pattern under this code.

[image: without debug paint]
[image: with debug paing]

```dart
return Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(
                bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1.0),
              ),
            ),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          document['postTitle'].toUpperCase(),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10.0,
                        ),
                        Text(document['postText']),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 100.0,
                  height: 100.0,
                  child: document['postPhoto'] != null
                      ? Image.network(
                          asyncSnapShot.data,
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        )
                      : null,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
```

I expect the post text spread all over available space.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Package https://pub.dev/packages/drop_cap_text, Maybe this will solve your issue.

Comment: I tried to use it, but it isn't efficient. So, I changed the design.